# Java slick command line app?

Tags: java, command-line

I want to make a slick java commandline app which doesnt include all the nasty "java -jar some.jar arguments"

instead, I would have it work just like

```
program -option argument
```

like any other commandline app. I use ubuntu linux, and it would be fine if it included a bit of .sh script or anything. I know I can just create a file with `java -jar program.jar` and do `chmod +x file`, afterwards I could run i with ./file, but then how can I pass the arguments to the program ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
java -jar program.jar $1 $2 $3
```

to access 1st, 2nd and 3rd argument of the script.

Example from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash2.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo name of script is $0
echo first argument is $1
echo second argument is $2
echo seventeenth argument is $17
echo number of arguments is $#
```

---

Or, even better, do as @nos suggests:

```
java -jar program.jar "$@"
```

Comment: Or just forward all arguments to the java app . e.g. `java -jar $@`

Comment: if you'd like, place the bash script in the bash PATH

Comment: Just to be really picky, I think "$@" handles quoting better (quotes each argument, which is handy if there are spaces in paths, say). man bash would tell you for certain...

Comment: @pdbartlett, could you elaborate?

Comment: Even better, use `java -jar program.jar "$@"`. The quotes keep quoting so your parameters can also have spaces.

Comment: If you were calling `script.sh "hello world" blah blah`:

`$@` would expand to: `hello world blah blah` whereas

`"$@"` would expand to: `"hello world" "blah" "blah"`

Comment: Thanks @pdbartlett for the clear example! Updated the answer. (And set it as wiki)

Answer (score 0):

On **Linux** you can use [binfmt](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to be really slick and you are running on a platform that supports **bash**, you can hide the fact that you're using Java completely from the user by producing a self extracting archive.

Take a look at [this post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818) for some hints on how you to implement a self extracting archive.